# Is there a way to get all data from a firestore database using useCollectionData()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a React project and in it I have the following code: (using [this](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/blob/master/firestore/README.md) react hook for firebase)

```
const messagesRef = firestore.collection('messages');
const query = messagesRef.orederBy('createdAt').limit(25);
const [messages] = useCollectionData(query, {idField: 'id'});
```

Instead of this, I don't want the query to be ordered or have a limit, is there a way to make an "empty" query to get all the data from a certain collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass `messagesRef` instead of a query with `orderBy()` and `limit()` then the query should fetch all documents in the collection since a CollectionReference is a subclass of a Query:

```
const messagesRef = firestore.collection('messages');
const [messages] = useCollectionData(messagesRef, {idField: 'id'});
```